# why my datanode is not working in hadoop-2.8.0?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What should i do to make datanode run?

```
C:\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin>jps
11328 ResourceManager
14312 Jps
17352 NodeManager
6616 NameNode
```

I have installed hadoop-2.8.0 on my system. But I am facing this problem. Can anyone suggest any methods to solve this?

Comment: Look at the logs of the datanode process and see why it won't start

Comment: ok thanks i will look into it .